# In TLS 1.3, is the first Derived Secret always a constant value (in non-PSK handshakes)?

Tags: tls, hkdf

[RFC 5869 Defines HKDF-Extract](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869#section-2.2) in section 2.2 as:

```
HKDF-Extract(salt, IKM) -> PRK
```

[TLS 1.3 RFC 8446](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-7.1) defines the first part of the Key Schedule like this:

```
          0
          |
          v
PSK ->  HKDF-Extract = Early Secret
          | 
           ... <<< omitting unrelated lines >>> ...
          v
    Derive-Secret(., "derived", "")
          |
          v
(EC)DHE -> HKDF-Extract = Handshake Secret
```

And later confirms that if there is no PSK, the first Extract operation is on (0,0):

```
if PSK is not in use, Early Secret will still be HKDF-Extract(0, 0)
```

The result of HKDF-Extract(0, 0) will get fed into the Derive-Secret Operation as such:

```
Derive-Secret( [HKDF-Extract(0, 0)], "derive", "")
```

Which doesn't include a transcript hash.  Hence, this is put together from entirely prescribed values (0, 0, "derive").

**Q: Does this mean this value, which is then combined with the result of the (EC)DHE, is always constant?**

Effectively, an `HKDF-Extract` on (`0,0`), then an `HKDF-Expand-Label` on the result of the earlier Extract, plus the label "derived" plus an empty handshake transcript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q: Does this mean this value, which is then combined with the result of the (EC)DHE, is always constant?

Yes, the *Early Secret* Without pre-shared keys is always a constant value, i.e., $\mathrm{Extract(0,0)}$. As you point out, the same is true for the *Derived Early Secret*. This is fine since the latter value is used as salt to extract further keys from the DH shared secret.

Indeed, assuming a correct implementation, the key schedule uses ephemeral DH shares to compute a shared secret and then a handshake secret as follows: $\mathrm{HS} = \mathrm{Extract}(\mathrm{DES}, xy*G)$. Where: $\mathrm{HS}$ is the handshake secret, $\mathrm{DES}$ is the derived handshake secret used as the salt for $\mathrm{Extract}$, and finally, $xy*G$ is the DH shared secret.